# Regular expression to convert url parameter string into path

Tags: c#, .net, regex

Need regular expression to change below url

```
abc.aspx?str=blue+lagoon&id=1234
```

to

```
/blog/blue-lagoon/
```

Comment: in what language? This seems like innapropriate regex to me, more info please.

Comment: If it is indeed an URL, then `abc.aspx?id=1234&str=blue+lagoon` is a legal equivalent and should be considered as well.

Comment: Also, as worded, it is not clear why regex is needed at all here - sounds like a straightforward search & replace.

Comment: Basically an expression to strip the string  between "=" and "&" (For the above example--> blue+laggon) from the url and then add another string to it.

Comment: I need to pass the Regular expression to a CMS server for doing regex aliasing

Comment: Sounds like you want to use a URL rewriter. A bit more context here would help I think...

Answer (score 5):

in perl:

```
my $work_url = $original_url; 
$work_url =~ s/\+/-/g;
$url = '/blog/' . do { $work_url =~ m/\bstr=([\w\-]+)\b/; $1} . '/';
```

works for the example given.

inspired by Ragepotato:

```
$new_url = '/blog/'
    . sub { local $_ = shift; tr/+/-/; m/\bstr=([\w\-]+)\b/; $1 }->($orig_url)
    . '/';
```

And an stricter, less greedy regex for Ragepotatos post, untested:

```
Regex.Match(input.Replace("+", "-"),@"\bstr=(.*?)&").Groups[1].Value
```

Comment: You're welcome.   I'm sorry I don't know C#.net syntax yet or I'd be happy to post. I'm sure the regex would look similar, but the invocation..?  I'll read up a bit and see if I can wing it w/o a compiler.

Comment: This might get you close..  Syntax snagged from: http://www.radsoftware.com.au/articles/regexsyntaxadvanced.aspx


using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
Regex exp = new Regex( @"\bstr=([\w\+]+)\b" );  
string InputText = "abc.aspx?str=blue+lagoon&id=1234";  
MatchCollection MatchList = exp.Matches(InputText);  
Match FirstMatch = MatchList[0];  Console.WriteLine(FirstMatch.Value);

Answer (score 2):

C# .NET

```
string input = "abc.aspx?str=blue+lagoon&id=1234";

string output = "/blogs/" + Regex.Match(input.Replace("+", "-"),@"str=(.*)&").Groups[1].Value + "/";
```

Comment: nicely done. Needs a word boundary on the str and a non greedy capture (.*?)  don't you think?